# Is there an Angular way to keep div scroll locked to bottom of items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

This [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nT75k/2/) shows how to use jQuery to create a terminal-like effect where as items are added to a scrollable div, the scroll stays locked on the bottom.

Specifically `$cont[0].scrollTop = $cont[0].scrollHeight;` on line 7.

Is there a simple way to achieve the same effect the "Angular way" or is this a good example of when jQuery should be used in an Angular project?

Comment: `scrollTop` and `scrollHeight` are native properties, not jQuery, then they would be methods, as in `$element.scrollTop( $element.scrollHeight() )`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see example...

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/scPMvj5jodo0l4HvnOLi?p=preview)

no jQuery needed, just plain javascript:

```
terminal.scrollTop = terminal.scrollHeight
```